# How do I enable system sound (beeps, login)?

Tags: 11.10, sound, login

Small problem here. Since I installed (2nd time) Ubuntu 11.10 I can't hear the login sound, nor any "beep" sound when something went wrong. I may need your help here, because I can't find the solution in the "sound configuration"

Answer (score 2):

If sound does not work at all, it is a bug which is specific for your hardware - please fill a report ;-)

If there are applications which have got sound, klick on the gear on the upper right, then on system settings. Klick on audio, then raise the second volume control on the first tab. This tab is for system sounds. Check if the master volume is turned on, too. At last, if you mean your system beep, which is soldered on the mainboard, you have to load the kernel module "pcspkr".

```
sudo modprobe -v pcspkr
```

If you want to load it permanently, add a line "pcspkr" to /etc/modules.

Answer (score 2):

During four installs of Ubuntu 11.10 last few days I noticed in all cases the speaker was set to zero (muted speaker right top screen). Click on the speaker and set if to a non-zero (slide it up!).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try this solution for your problem.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (to execute the terminal) then write this command: `alsamixer`. Afterwards, the terminal is going to ask your password, write it and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Then in the terminal is going to appear the system sounds setting. Just turn all the volumes up, then try it to see if it works.