# How do I enable system sounds?

Tags: 12.10, sound, sound-theme

Lately I noticed that there aren't any sounds (beeps, boops, plinks, swooshes, etc.) when I press buttons of any sort or if an event happens, such as opening/closing a tab in chromium, pressing a button in the system settings, the login jingle, etc.

### How do I enable these sounds?

---

**As a note:** I suppose this question is a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68814/how-do-i-enable-system-sound-beeps-login), but that question is about 11.10, and the answer there did not solve my issue. I turned up the volume all the way in `System Settings -> Sound -> Sound Effects`, and my master volume is also turned up all the way.

Also, my sound does work, so that's not the issue.

Comment: I miss 'em too. Sometimes, I pass by somewhere and hear the Windows welcome. I Googled a bit and got the impression that sounds have fallen out of favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Enable Sound Effects

In addition to turning **ON Alert volume** from **System Settings... > Hardware > Sound > Sound effects**;

1) Install **Ubuntu Tweak** *(For more info: [www.webupd8.org/2012/11/ubuntu-tweak-gets-full-ubuntu-1210.html](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/ubuntu-tweak-gets-full-ubuntu-1210.html))*

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

2) Go to **Tweaks > Sound**

3) Enable **Event sounds** / **Input feedback** and select a **Sound theme**, e.g. Ubuntu studio...

---

### Enable Login Sound

To enable the old [login sound](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NL3c4l6G6pM), you need to add a new entry to your startup programs:

1. Open `Startup Applications` from the dash
2. Click <kbd>Add</kbd>
3. In the "Command:" line, enter the following command: `/usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --id="desktop-login" --description="play login sound"`
4. The name and comment aren't necessary, but it may be helpful to name it something like "Login Sound" so you can identify it later if necessary.
5. Click <kbd>Save</kbd>

That's it! You should hear the familiar login sound next time you log in.

Comment: That had enabled my sound effects (Thanks so much!), but not the old login sound. Luckily, that was only a google search away, and it's fairly simple to add!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I used pavucontrol.

1. Install pavucontrol: sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
2. Run: sudo pavucontrol
3. Go to the "Playback" tab and adjust the slider for 'System Sounds'. Done!