# Enable old Ubuntu Startup/Shutdown sounds in Trusty Tahr?

Tags: 14.04, login, shutdown

I want to enable the sounds shown in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ul3c6UEqo4U) video (I want the startup sound to play when any user sucsessfully logs in to the computer, and the shutdown sound to play when they shut it down.)

Comment: Same as this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/258589/how-do-i-enable-system-sounds

Comment: @fossfreedom didn't seem to work for me...